# Refreshing a DataGridView binded with a access database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created in Visual Basic .net a new DataGridView in my form. I have used the wizard to show some fields of a table in my access database.
I would like to add a refresh button and force the datagrid to load the data again from the database, but I'm not sure how to do that. I have tried several refresh method but it does not work.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the datasource again. I've never done this with an Access database but here's how you might do it using ADO.NET with SQL

```
Using command As New SqlCommand("CommandText Goes Here", "ConnectionString goes here")
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim ds As New DataSet("Results")
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        da.Fill(ds)
        myGrid.DataSource = ds
    End Using
End Using
```

So you could wrap that up in a button click event.

There are a ton of other ways of doing this but that works for me.

Comment: I have tried that with this code
       Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
        con.Open()
        Dim comando As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT IdEmpleado, Nombre, contrasena FROM Empleados", con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet("Results")
        EmpleadosTableAdapter.Fill(ds)
        con.Close()
And I'm getting an error:
A System.Data.DataSet can not be converter into...